# Browse Servlet for CKEditor to Browse Database items

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, ckeditor

I have database entities called Category, Article, Poll etc..
I need to write a browse servlet for CKEditor through which I should be able to browse DB table rows to link up with text in editor. Please let me know whether it is possible. If possible please give me a way to proceed.